# Does anyone have a way to add multiple children to a Xamarin Grid with just one statement?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I found this Grid extension for Xamarin:

```
    public static void AddChild(this Grid grid, View view, int row = 0, int column = 0, int rowspan = 1, int colspan = 1)
    {
        if (row < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("row");
        if (column < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("column");
        if (rowspan <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rowspan");
        if (colspan <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("colspan");
        if (view == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("view");
        Grid.SetRow((BindableObject)view, row);
        Grid.SetRowSpan((BindableObject)view, rowspan);
        Grid.SetColumn((BindableObject)view, column);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan((BindableObject)view, colspan);
        grid.Children.Add(view);
    }
```

I am using it like this:

```
    this.AddChild(gridIconFrame, 0, 0);
    this.AddChild(textLabel, 0, 1);
    this.AddChild(valueLabel, 0, 2);
    this.AddChild(arrowFrame, 0, 3);
```

What I would like to do is have another extension that has the functionality to enable me to code this:

```
    this.AddChildren((gridIconFrame, 0, 0),
                     (textLabel, 0, 1),
                     (valueLabel, 0, 2),
                     (arrowFrame, 0, 3));
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction and give me some suggestions on how I can achieve the code above with another extension?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jason's comment suggesting use of `params` keyword, this is as close as I could come to your desired syntax:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var grid = new object();

            AddChildren(grid,
                D(new View(), 1, 1),
                D(new View(), 1, 2));


            static Item D(View view0, int row0, int column0)
            {
                return new Item(view0, row0, column0);
            }

            static void AddChildren(object grid, params Item[] items)
            {
                // loop to add items to grid.
                foreach (Item item in items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("add an item");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public View view { get; set; }
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int column { get; set; }

        public Item(View view0, int row0, int column0)
        {
            view = view0;
            row = row0;
            column = column0;
        }
    }

    class View
    {

    }
}
```

I did not find any way to completely avoid C#'s strict syntax; my work-around was to:

- create a class Item that holds the parameters;
- create a method with a very short name `D`, and call that method to construct each Item.

You could easily change "AddChildren" to be an extension method for Gid. But you'll still need `D(..)` to convert each set of parameters into an Item for AddChildren.

(I made `grid` an `object`, so I could easily write this example. Change it to the `Grid` class.)